# Is a Wild Card SSL Certificate recommended?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have below domains, buying a single wild card certificate beneficial? Or do I need to buy separate SSL certificates.

1. abc.example.com.**au**
2. abc.example.com.**nz**
3. abc.api.module.example.com
4. abc.api.global.example.com

Do I need to consider anything, when buying the SSL for the above domain. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Wildcard certificates can only be used for different subdomains of the same root domain, not across entirely different domains.

Comment: You have a third possibility: one certificate valid for these 4 names.

Comment: With your example, for a wildcard you need 4 wildcard certificate, you can't have one wildcard that matches more than one of these names : the * is one the left only ( example.* or abc.*.example.com are not possible), and only valid for one level (*.example.com is NOT valid for a.b.example.com)

Comment: Thanks Tom for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a better question for ServerFault or SuperUser, but since you're here, a wildcard certificate will only work for subdomains and only one level deep, so it would not work for any of the examples you mentioned.

Example:  A cert with `cn=*.example.com` would work with `a.example.com` or `b.example.com`, but not `1.a.example.com`.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate for more details.

Also, when using a wildcard does make it simpler to manage your certificates and renewals and applying updated certs and whatnot because the generation process only has to be done once and the same files and configs can be copied to all servers.  Consider though that, if there is some kind of security issue with the wildcard cert, then it would affect all servers that use that cert. So a breach on one server would affect all servers and a problem with one would require an update to all servers that use it.

For these reasons, I generally use wildcard certs for non-production systems, and individual certs for production systems.

Answer (score 0):

Single Wildcard SSL Certificate will not work in your all sub-domains.

You have now 3 options.

1. Get two different wildcard domains
2. Get a Multi Domain SSL (it will allow you to add sub-domains as well)
3. Get a Multi Domain Wildcard SSL Certificate (combination of 100 multiple domains and unlimited number of level-1 sub-domains).